# Актуализация ветки в git

Tags: git

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно я делаю что-то не так...

У меня есть рабочая ветка и во время разработки я пушил в гит изменения, в это время origin/main обновлялся. Я хочу стянуть все изменения и актуализировать локальную рабочею ветку и main.

1. Я запушил последние изменения рабочей ветки в гит.
2. Перешел в локальный main стянул все изменения в него (git pull)
3. Перехожу обратно в рабочею ветку и прописываю (git rebase main). Возникают конфликты (что ожидаемо) моя рабочая ветка откатывается до первого коммита из этой ветки и предлагает решать конфликты с первым коммитом, а не с последним...

Comment: Что-то не понимаю чем вы хотите актуализировать удаленный репозиторий? Тем что на локальном? Или вы хотите с удаленного стянуть все изменения на локальный?

Comment: С удаленного на локальный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rebase так и работает. он переписывает историю. и если у вас конфликт в первом коммите, то вам придется решать его ни 1 даже раз, а на протяжении всех коммитов ребейза.
сам коммит, после решения конфилктов, будет переписан.

даже если вы пойдете по этому пути, возникнет неприятная ситуация, что в будущем вы даже не увидите "что было на стороне А, что на стороне Б, как вы это решили?".

а вот мердж наоборот, сравнит целые ветки и выкинет все конфликты 1 раз. и у него как раз можно будет посмотреть стороны А, Б, как решился конфликт.

лично я предпочитаю следующую стратегию в вашем случае:
делать ребейз, если он без конфликтов.
есть вылез хотя бы 1 -> аборт и подтягивать изменения через мердж.
да, ветка будет некрасивой, зато я в любой момент увижу и проблемное место, и как оно решилось.

Comment: Получается что мне нужно каждый мой коммит исправить) и так пока не дойду до последнего? а если использовать git rebase --skip в первом коммите и так пока не дойдет до последнего? Меня просто смущает что моя рабочая ветка откатывается)

Comment: @Moroshka почему "рабочая ветка" откатывается? если скипать, то конечно. но если вы все таки решите все конфликты ребейза - все подтянется. но я уже описал, какие у этого подхода минусы.

Comment: Спасибо все получилось. Спасибо за развернутый ответ.